# Project works fine when accessing via 127.0.0.1:8000 but error via localhost public folder

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3

I have a project (`test`) that **works perfectly fine** when accessed via 127.0.0.1:8000 but when I access it via localhost/test/public, errors occur.

**1.** `app.js` and `app.css` are not found

my solution:

```
 <!-- defined before -->
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- solution: change`mix` to`asset` -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct solution but the error is gone for now. **BUT** there is a new error.

**2.** `API` can't be found even though the `API` is being shown in `php artisan route:list`

I have worked on a Laravel project before with just vanillaJS and jQuery and it works fine in both 127.0.0.1:8000 and localhost/test/public but this project I'm working on now is Laravel with Vuejs 3 so maybe I'm missing some setup?

Answer (score 0):

All public APIs on Laravel are http(s)://domain.name/api/yourroute